# ValueError creating an array from a list

Tags: python

Trying to create an array from a list fails for me, under some cases. The error is: 'ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence'

The basic case works as expected:

```
foo = [(0,1),(2,3),(4,5)]
bar=np.array(foo)
```

But:

```
foo = [ ("Hello", [0,1,2,3]) , ("Goodbye",[9,8,7,6]) ]
bar=np.array(foo)
```

Blows up with the described error. Why does it fail when the list contains an array? What is the pythonic solution?

Answer (score 2):

The answer to "Why does it fail ?" is in the description of the [ndarray](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.html) object you'd like to create.

> An array object represents a multidimensional, homogeneous array of fixed-size items

It blows up because your second case is not a **homogeneous array of fixed-size items**